# Rsync without ssh access

Tags: ssh

There is a host of computers and one of them needs to Rsync a specific folder from each of the other computers.

The way its done right now is that this central computer has ssh access to all those other computers.

Is it possible to only gain access to a single folder in another machine?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to gain access to remote folders, and SSH is one of them. A central computer with access to the others is the easiest way of keeping them all in synch. But 1. this isn't a security question; 2. you need to give us a lot more information: what operating systems, what the trust relationship between the computers is, what protocols your network lets though, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH with a user that only has read/write access to one specific folder on the other machine. Some more information on [file permissions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140313174957/http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html).

Also check up on [chroot](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Dictionary/html/c.html), which sandboxes the user to a single subdirectory - it's a bit more work.

Comment: The first link is dead